# how does the index argument work in the reduce.method in Javascript

Tags: indexing, reduce

I'm trying to understand the reduce method but I got stuck over something. If I write:

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5];


const sum = myArr.reduce((acc,el)=>{
return acc+el

});


console.log(`The sum is ${sum}`);
```

I get the correct output of 22 which is my sum.

But if I write this:

```
const items = [{
name: "Bike",
price: 100
},
{
name: "TV",
price: 200
},
{
name: "Album",
price: 10
},
{
name: "Book",
price: 5
},
{
name: "Phone",
price: 500
},
{
name: "Computer",
price: 1000
}
]


const total = items.reduce((acc, el) => {
  return acc + el.price
});


console.log(total);
```

I don't get the total unless I initialise the index to 0. I don't understand why in the first case it works but not in the second.
Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .reduce functions seems to initially assigns "acc" the type of the first element of what is being looped through, before it knows what you will be doing with it (could be math or string manipulation). You are trying to do math.

In the first case that type is a number, so all is well, but in the second, it is an object. Thus in the second case, you are adding a number (el.price) to an object ({name: "Bike", price: 100}), thus converting it to a string. From here on out, you will just be concatenating strings rather then doing math.

By setting acc to 0, ur reassigning it a type of number, and thus it works.

So I think it is good practise to always assign acc in the reduce function to avoid these types of error.

Answer (score 1):

The return of the reducer function (in this case const reducer =...) is assigned to the accumulator, and it is "remembered" across each iteration so if you try this way:

```
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => ({ 
  price: accumulator.price + currentValue.price 
});

items.reduce(reducer);

// console.log outputs { price: 1815 }
```

Because you are handling objects, you need to return an object because if you return just `(acc, cur) => acc.price + cur.price` you get a NaN error because a number is not compatible with an object (and the return of the reducer function is assigned to the accumulator).

Check these console logs, I believe they will help understand what is going on with the reducer:

[image]

Note that the first time the reducer runs the accumulator is the index 0 of the array.

Please let me know if you have any other questions in the comments below.